# Find a bit with no duplicates among multiple bits in Java

Tags: java, set, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a project in java and I'm using bits to represent possible numbers. By giving each numbers a bit something like {2} would be 100 in binary aka 2^2 and {0,1,2} would be 111 in binary aka 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0. I'm trying to find out whether there is a single bit that doesn't reoccur within several sets.
example:
from these sets {3,5,7}{3,5,9}{3,5,9}{1,5,6,9}{5,6,7,9}{3,7,9}
I want to find {1} because it is the only one without duplicates

I have actually tried a similar problem in python and I also figured that if there is a way to do it using sets there is probably a way to do it using bits, but the way in which I did it was just brute force. You can technically just **and** all combinations(in my case 23) of 2 bits, then **or** them but I was kinda hoping for a faster method with less loops.

Comment: Using bits to represent a set can only indicate element presence. If you want to indicate presence *and* duplicate, you need more than one bit. If you want to store sets as bits, you have to use bit operations between sets to determine duplicates. Otherwise, you can use Java collections - use `Map` with set elements as the key, and an integer count as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two bitmasks, one tracking which bits have been seen at least once, and one tracking which bits have been seen more than once.

```
int atLeastOnce = 0;
int moreThanOnce = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sets.length; i++) {
    moreThanOnce |= sets[i] & atLeastOnce;
    atLeastOnce |= sets[i];
}
```

After this, `atLeastOnce & ~moreThanOnce` gives a mask of the bits that were set exactly once. You can out whether there is *any* such bit by simply comparing that to zero, and you can get the index of the lowest element that occurs exactly once (if there is one) with `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros`.

Comment: Thanks for the support, for my first post everyone kinda seems aggressive. I’m also new to bit manipulation and it just seems too different. My bad for posting such an easy question

Comment: @AlexanderLiu maybe this helps: you can mostly think of the basic bitwise operations as set operations (`&` is intersection, `|` is union, `^` is symmetric difference, `a & ~b` is the "normal" set difference) and if you can write your algorithm in terms of those "bulk operations" between sets then that translates into a bitwise algorithm when the sets are represented as bitsets. This algorithm above can be viewed that way as well, building up a set of elements seen at least once and a set of elements seen more than once, with the "set of elements seen exactly once" being their difference.